# How can I load data into an HTML div tag?

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to create a product review web page. The product review has product image, title, description, etc, in a SQL database. How can I load this datas into an HTML div tag, using ASP.NET?

Comment: I think this is a related post .. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084599/problem-with-insert-html-data-to-a-div

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your div

```
<div runat="server" Id="dataDiv"></div>
```

And then in your CodeBehind you can call your div with its Id

```
dataDiv.InnerHtml= YourData;// this can be anything from database or a variable
```

hope it helped.

Thanks,
Aneef

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `ID` property and `runat="server"` to `<div>` to be able to reference it from code behind, and add HTML using the `InnerHtml` property.

You can also use an `<asp:Panel>` control, which emits a `<div>`, and insert your HTML by adding a `Literal` control from code behind that contains your markup. That approach also allows you to add controls to the `<div>`, should you need to.